# Prevent Account creation upon Lead conversion

Tags: lead-conversion

Prevent Account creation upon Lead conversion

While doing the lead conversion from UI, there are 2 options shown in the screen:
Option 1.  Account field is prepopulated which comes from the Company field of Lead.
Option 2. User can select Account from the lookup icon.
I want user always follows the Option 2. User should be restricted if Option 1 is followed.
Is there a way to meet this requirement? 
Thanks!
Milan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a couple of triggers and an Apex class. The point here is that you need to detect when conversion occurs, and if an account was created as a result of that conversion.

I'm not going to write a proper trigger framework; I leave this as an exercise to the reader.

---

```
public class StaticStorage {
  public static Set<Id> newRecordIds = new Set<Id>();
}
```

---

```
trigger storeNewAccountIds on Account (after insert) {
    // Just remember we are in record creation
    StaticStorage.newRecordIds.addAll(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
}
```

---

```
trigger checkForNewAccountOnLeadConvert on Lead (after update) {
    for(Lead record: Trigger.new) {

        // If the account Id is in the set, it's a new record...
        if(StaticStorage.newRecordIds.contains(record.ConvertedAccountId)) {
            record.ConvertedAccountId.addError('You may not create a new account while converting a lead.');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks sfdcfox!

I have tried do achieve this requirement through validation rule and Lead mapping concept.

Lead  default value = checked
Account default value = unchecked

Map the fields to each other

Create a Validation Rule on the Account object like this

AND(
ISNEW(),
Checkbox = TRUE
)

Thanks,
Milan